# Does RTP Packets using RTSP protocol contain both audio and video

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, live-streaming, rtsp-client

I am developing a client program which will display the media captured from IP camera. So I want to whether the RTP packets using RTSP protocol contain both audio and video if contains both how should I extract it?

Answer (score 2):

RTSP stream does not carry video/audio itself, it provides a method to control independent RTP video and audio streams (they are in turn independent one from another).

One of the options though is when RTP streams are tunnelled through RTSP connection, in which case all communication might be taking place through single TCP connection.

Comment: I know that RTSP is controlling protocol RTP packets are actual carriers but then why I get no output when I try to extract audio data from a packet.

Comment: What packet you are expecting it in? Would you ming throwing in more details on what you do?

Comment: I am building an client application using Gstreamer just as I told you that the I am able to extract and display video from the RTP packets that are streamed from server but when instead of RTP h264 extractor plugin I use rtpmp4adepay(mp4a audio extractor from RTP packets) and passes it to proper element it gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the SDP returned in the `SETUP` request to the RtspServer.

There should be a MediaInformation for each stream available.

That will tell you if there is audio or video etc...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol